# Experiences with Zoho Creator?

Tags: database, zoho

I wish to create an online system to track some things (e.g., a database with children, where each child has 1 or more visits from doctors). I want the users to be able to enter data as well as search for it, especially from mobile devices. So, this is a custom mobile online DB app of modest but non-zero size.

I've looked into DabbleDB and Zoho Creator, looking for an easy solution that will have low-cost maintenance.

Although I feel my app is not too complicated, I find that if I want to do something slightly out of their mainstream, I hit walls. For example, dealing with many-to-many relationships, or with 100K records, or doing an involved mathematical calculation for a field.

What are people's experiences with these online DB apps? Should I keep pushing ahead, or just write a custom app myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried building a simple web application with Zoho Creator and got so frustrated that I am now looking for a different solution. I consider Zoho Creator to be at a point right now suitable for educational purposes but I would not consider using it for a functional application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this systems not bad,but they are paid. Their price impresses!
Use free application, example [mytaskhelper](http://mytaskhelper.com)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use it for personal and business use.
In fact, I created 3 applications that were used in real business environmnets and solved a lot of problems with no extra investment.

You can easily create applications that deal with 10s of thousands of records with user-friendly forms, even embedded in other websites.

More BI tasks can be done by connecting Creator to Reports. And this is just one example.

I think you should seriously give it a second thought.

Comment: How can I find my authtoken in Zoho Creator? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever look at [Viravis](http://www.viravis.com). It may be the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using LongJump, The solution allows you to build apps easily using one of the several available templates. I am very satisfied with it.

Comment: To ask something from OP, you should better leave a comment under the question.